# I am getting negative values for the R2 Squared after doing the linear regression on my data. What does it Suggest?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I am getting negative values for the R2 Squared after doing the linear regression on my data. What does it Suggest?  Does it suggest the output is useless?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pretty good treatment of this already existing on the stats stackexchange, which I posted as reference since most of this answer will be similar, but possibly less extensive.

The short is that your `R^2` value is comparing your regression to a horizontal line. If your `R^2` value is less performant than a horizontal line you'll see a negative value.

Image posted below for reference:
[image]